# json string having id and name? using c sharp

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, json, kendo-ui

here is my json string

```
 var people = '{"Id": 101020001 ,  "Title": "subsidary","Id": 103010001 ,  "Title": "LOAN FROM BANK ?","Id": 104010001 ,  "Title": "FAWAD","Id": 104010002 ,  "Title": "GETING","Id": 104010003}
```

i built it as

```
     string MyDictionaryToJson(Dictionary<int, string > dict)
       {
     var entries = dict.Select(d =>
         string.Format("\"Id\": {0} ,  \"Title\": \"{1}\"", d.Key, string.Join(",", d.Value)));
     return "{" + string.Join(",", entries) + "}";
 }
```

but i want to populate kendo grid so ID is not known i want it like that

```
"{"Id":"101020001" , "Title":"titlesubsidary"},{"Id":"101020002" , "Title":"titlenext"}, {"Id":"101020003" , "Title":"titleagain"}
```

kendo combo box

```
    var people = '<%=jsonS %>'
  $('#Text1').kendoComboBox({

       dataTextField: 'Title',
      dataValueField: 'Id',
      template: "<table><tr><td width='100px'>${ Id}</td><td width='100px'>${ Title }</td></tr></table>",
      dataSource: { data: people }

  });
```

> error:ReferenceError: Id is not defined

Comment: Because your JSON isn't valid. Use JSON.NET to create JSON

Comment: Don't try to create json manually....it is far too error prone as witnessed by your invalid output

Comment: I agree with the statements above you should use some type of serialization library, also one thing to note is you have Id as your dataValueField in javascript but the property is called ID with the D capitalized.

Comment: now i have changed the string format and also captialization still saying the same  that id missing what to do with that json to acheive id too

Answer (score 1):

Because your Json string is not valid. 
You shouldn't build it manually. Try to use [Json.NET](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json).
If you want chceck how Json is maaped to objects you can use [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).